# Android cannot identify id name

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile

The app is not accepting the id name. I have already tried copy-pasting the same name so as to avoid any errors. I have also imported the `android.R` class.

It says `"Cannot resole symbol 'quantity_text_view"`

The code that I used is:

```
android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
```

All the id's that I used in my xml file are not working and showing similar errors.

Also, initially the MainAcivity.java was not accepting the `R.id.text1` so I imported the `android.R` class.

The exact code I used is:

```
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
```

Please note that I use Android Studio.

Comment: Build -> Clean Project / Rebuild Project

Comment: Post your xml file and Manifest

Comment: Be sure your ressources files names don't contain any illegal characters (no space, no upper case...)

Comment: @Priyansh solved?

Comment: Yup its solved... The 'Rebuild Project' feature help... Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

1) Delete the "gen" folder in your project, clean and rebuild

2) Remove "R" import Then Goto R.id and Import R as your Project package name

for example my project package is `abc.xyz` 
then import should be

```
import abc.xyz.R
```